# file::tail and sending email of lines during sleep?

Tags: perl

I know that file::tail blocks on read while it waits to search a file. However during that wait interval is it possible to send what lines the file has found all at once? Instead of it sending an email per line it finds? so if i have lines:

ISSUE 112323

SOMETHING

ISSUE 93483948

SOMETHING

It send an email for the first issue, and second email for the second issue. Instead of an aggregate of both. I obviously cant put the subroutine outside the while since it doesn't exit. what is the best way to handle this? Thoughts? Thank you!

```
my agg_lines=();
use File::Tail;
$file=File::Tail->new(name=>$name, maxinterval=>300, adjustafter=>7);
while (defined($line=$file->read)) {
    if($line=~m/.\|ISSUE  \|./)
    {
        push(@agg_lines,$line);
    }
      send_mail(join("\n",@agglines));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::Tail qw( );

my $tail = File::Tail->new(name => $name);
while (my $block = $tail->read()) {
    $tail->nowait(1);
    while (my $line = $tail->read()) { $block .= $line; }
    $tail->nowait(0);

    send_mail($block);
}
```